# Cargar imagen al cambiarla en Firebase Storage

Tags: java, android, firebase, activity, fragment

estoy creando una app con un perfil de usuario, mi main de app es un Tabbed Activity, por lo que cuenta con 4 fragments, inicio, busqueda, noticias y perfil. En el fragment de perfil he creado un button que permite editar la info del usuario, donde se crea otro fragment para esto. Cuando pongo cambiar imagen, se abre la camara, toma la foto, la sube a firebase y este fragment se cierra y vuelve al de perfil, el problema esta en que no se actualiza la foto si me quedo en el fragment de perfil, pero se actualiza cuando cambio a cualquiera de los otros 3 fragments y vuelvo a perfil. Alguna ayuda que me puedan dar? dejo los codigos de ambos:

Fragment Perfil:

```
    bt_configperfil = root.findViewById(R.id.perfil_editarperf);

    tv_nombre = root.findViewById(R.id.perfil_nombre);
    tv_descripcion = root.findViewById(R.id.perfil_descripcion);

    civ_perfil = root.findViewById(R.id.perfil_image);

    ll_pubs = root.findViewById(R.id.perfil_ll_fotos);

    uid = Objects.requireNonNull(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()).getUid();

    perfil = myref.child("Perfil")
            .child(uid + "/fotoDePerfil.jpg");

    Task<Uri> task = perfil.getDownloadUrl();

    task.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
            GlideApp.with(Objects.requireNonNull(Perfil.this.getContext()))
                .load(uri)
                .into(civ_perfil);
        }
    });

    bt_configperfil.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            editarPerfil();
        }
    });
```

Fragment Editar Perfil:

```
if(requestCode == CAMERA_TOKEN){
        final Uri miPath = Uri.fromFile(fileImage);
        perfilpic = mystorage
                .child("Perfil")
                .child(uid + "/fotoDePerfil.jpg");

        UploadTask uploadTask = perfilpic.putFile(miPath);

        uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                progressBar.dismiss();
                assert getFragmentManager() != null;
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(Config_perfil.this).commit();
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Foto de perfil cambiada",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        })
                .addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        progressBar.show();
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        progressBar.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(Config_perfil.this.getContext(),
                                "Cancelado",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

    }else if(requestCode == GALLERY_TOKEN){
        image_gallery = data.getData();

        perfilpic = mystorage
                .child("Perfil")
                .child(uid + "/fotoDePerfil.jpg");

        UploadTask task = perfilpic.putFile(image_gallery);

        task.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                progressBar.dismiss();
                assert getFragmentManager() != null;
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(Config_perfil.this).commit();
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Foto de perfil cambiada",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        })
                .addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        progressBar.show();
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        progressBar.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(),
                                "Cancelado",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
    }
```

Comment: El GlideApp, tendrá cache, prueba a 'Glide.get(context).clearDiskCache()' o mirate el 'signature' de Glide

Answer (score 0):

Puedes refrescar ese fragment que indicas si controla el ciclo de vida.

```
@Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }
```

Cuando vuelvas del fragment perfil, debería sobreescribir el método onResume y entonces llamar para que refresque la imagen.

Answer (score 0):

Para ver los cambios en tiempo real, debes usar `addSnapshotListener` para recibir los cambios que realices en Firebase y se vean al instante sin tener que realizar el cambio de fragmentos. Sigue la documentación oficial de Firebase

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen?hl=es-419

```
final DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("cities").document("SF");
ListenerRegistration registration = docRef.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
@Override
public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot snapshot,
                    @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
    if (e != null) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Listen failed.", e);
        return;
    }

    if (snapshot != null && snapshot.exists()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Current data: " + snapshot.getData());
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "Current data: null");
    }
}
});
```

No olvides si utilizas `addSnapshotListener`, debes terminar cerrar el listener para que no siga en curso al cerrar el cambiar de fragment y te genere problemas.

```
@Override
public void onStop(){
registration.remove();
super.onStop();
}
```